# Where to find command in ubuntu 14.04 to mount the ntfs partition when clicked on the icon?

Tags: unity, mount, icons, ntfs

My question seems to be related to auto mount partition when login, but it is more of learning about the inner command used by ubuntu OS for mounting the drive when the icon is clicked.

So, my question is:

1. Where to find that command which is used by Ubuntu to mount the partition shown as icon in Unity?
2. Where to configure the options of the same so that it can mount with executable permissions?
3. I think, if the above questions get answered, can I use the same for startup application command? so that I need not to change any settings where I have hard coded the location of the partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following command worked for me:

```
udisksctl mount --block-device  /dev/sda3
```

Answer (score 0):

If partition is shown in Unity it is already mounted. Mounting file systems is done by command *mount* and it is quite wide topic. You can access not so user friendly, but very detailed manual by command: *man mount*. Good luck!

Comment: I'm afraid it is not the case, because after booting the ubuntu, although there is an icon for the drive but it is not in mount state and also, the directory in /media/user/ is missing. But when I click on that icon, I can find a directory with uid in /media/user. Also, I observed that after clicking, I could find the unmount option in the right click menu of the icon (which was missing earlier). So it concludes that it is already not in mount condition.

Comment: Secondly, I know about mount command but I think, ubuntu uses a different mechanism (probably wrapper function) and therefore it automatically creates a mount point in /media/user with directory name as <uid> and on unmounting it, ubuntu removes that directory. I basically want to know how to configure that mechanism which ubuntu uses.